# Scraping a website but the order of ratings vary

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

built a scraper for glassdoor.com out of curiosity and as a learning experience, however just realized that the website has some gimmicks and I don't have any idea how to take them in to consideration.

Attached a picture to visualize the problem, every review has these categories in it, and in my original script I had used the nth number to select each of these, so Work/Life Balance is the 1st, Culture & Values the second, Diversity & Inclusion third, and so forth, but I just realized that the third object is not diversity & inclusion always, for the reviews where there is no rating for Diversity & Inclusion the third one returns the third one in the list (Career opportunities in the case of the image).

I would imagine there was a way to go around this, for example for each review retrieve all of the combinations of ratings available, they are clearly visible while inspecting (Work/Life Balance</div) for example, but for the life of me I can't return the text) and the class beneath it (class="css-xd4dom e1hd5jg10").

TLDR:
The 3rd rating is Diversity & Inclusion for those that have given the rating for it, but if they skipped this and rated everything else some other rating will pop up as the 3rd one.

Would like to come up with another solution for this

[2 Different reviews with different ratings given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxE3H.png)

[Key/Value for each?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0mAr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to select the `li` (and its descendant `span` with the star rating) based on the text of the `li` element's first child `div`, e.g.

```xml
//li
   [div[1]='Work/Life Balance']
   /div/span
      [contains(@class, 'gd-ui-star')]
```